# console.log prints undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

When I try to print a simple string with console.log(), it does not print the string out but rather it returns undefined:

```
> console.log("Hello")
< undefined
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You do require to post your code/test environment in order to get help.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't print `Hello` followed by a new line on which `undefined` appears?

Comment: Are you sure that the report of `undefined` doesn't occur **after** the log of `"Hello"` and not instead of it?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nTYWxwq.png — Cannot reproduce. You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: It doesn't print `undefined` it returns `undefined`.

Comment: @David Thomas. No, it only prints undefined

Comment: Add a screeshot or something.

Comment: `console.log("Hello")` will print `Hello`, then return `undefined`.
If you need to return "Hello", you can define a function that will return "Hello", then run it: `function test(){ return "Hello";} test();`

Comment: @GuillaumeGeorges — No. The OP says the output is *only* `undefined`, not the expected output followed by `undefined`.

Comment: @MatthiasSchmidt — No. The OP says the output is *only* `undefined`, not the expected output followed by `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your console log levels configuration. Chances are you unchecked `info` :

[image]

Answer (score -1):

because when you write in console it will print the return value of the function, when the function you called have no explicit return javascript implicitly call return undefined.
so when you write `console.log("hello")` it will return undefined so console print undefined for you

Answer (score -2):

just place your javascript.min.js file within the body tag of html and test